# .Issue related to SetFocusOnError property in requiredField validator

Tags: c#, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I have an asp.net WebApplication. i have added one requiredfieldvalidation on UserName textbox field. i have set SetFocusonError = "true" in RequiredField validator..

however when i try to tab out from username without filling username textbox, it shouldn't focus out from the textbox, it is working well in other browser without FireFox.

In firefox, when pressing tab key loss the focus from the username textbox.

why it is not working only in firefox ?? and what is the solution?

Thanks..